# fgets to read particular size

Tags: c, input, fopen, fgets

I'm trying to write a program that reads a certain amount of characters from a file name given from command line. Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f;
    char* fileName = argv[1];
    char buf[40];

    f = fopen(fileName, "r");

    while(!feof(f)){
        fgets(buf, 10, f);
        printf("%s\n", buf);

    }
    fclose(f);

    return 1;
}
```

Say in this particular case I need first 10 chars, then the next 10 chars, etc until the file is over. However, when I run this code it doesn't actually give me the right output. I tried 11 as well since the documentation said fgets() reads n-1 characters, but that doesn't work either. Some stuff at the beginning is read, but nothing afterwards is and it just gives me a bunch of blanks. Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of `feof` and instead check the return value of `fgets`. Otherwise, it should work reasonably well, except you want to pass `11` to read up to 10 bytes. One byte is needed to hold the string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `fread`, like this:

```
fread(buf, 10, 1, f);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but for my particular homework, I am required to use fgets.

Comment: @Kevin - `fgets()` reads a line up to the number of characters specified. If your line is shorter than 10 characters you will read just that. If your want to read binary data, you may get results all over the place.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera - Can you explain a little more about why binary data would not work properly?

Comment: @Kevin - when dealing with text some characters (bytes) have special meaning. This doesn't apply for binary data.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` is intended to read a line, up to a maximum length. If you want to read 10 characters at a time, regardless of line breaks, you probably want to use `fread` instead:

Either way, you definitely do *not* want to use `while (!feof(f))`. You probably want something like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    char buf[40];
    FILE *f;
    if (NULL == (f=fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t len;
    while (0 < (len=fread(buf, 10, 1, f)))
        printf("%*.*s\n", len, len, buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It tells me too few arguments for format for the printf line when I try using your while loop part.

Comment: Seg faulted. The file I was given was a binary file. Sorry for this confusion. Its text with a bunch of ^@^@.. I assume that indicates null characters.

Comment: @Kevin: binary data shouldn't cause a seg fault, *but* to get a meaningful printout, you're probably doing to have to do something like a hex-dump, and only print the character representation for "printable" characters (letters, digits, punctuation, but not most control characters and such). You also want to use "rb" as the mode string when you open a binary file (though on some OSes it makes no difference, you still want to do it for portability).

Answer (score 0):

It works almost ok if you remove the `\n` from your `printf` format string (assuming that you want to basically echo a whole file as is).

I would also loop based on `fgets(...) != NULL` since `feof()` will return a true value **after** `fgets` errors and hits EOF, so your last buffer-full will be printed twice. You could make a small change to your code as so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f;
    char* fileName = argv[1];
    char buf[40];

    f = fopen(fileName, "r");

    while(fgets(buf, 10, f))
        printf("%s", buf);

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, as others have stated, while I took too long to answer, `fread` may be a better alternative since `fgets` won't necessarily read 10 chars; it'll stop at every newline and you don't care about reading a line at a time.

Comment: I tried it without the \n and its just whatever incorrect output i got before minus the newlines. Also I changed the feof and still no luck.

Comment: @Kevin can you provide an example input file? I'm using this actual code as the input and it's printing it out properly. You're not trying to print a binary file are you?

Comment: I am trying to use a binary file. I'm so sorry I didn't specify in the description. This is probably why none of the answers work. The file is basically words with ^@^@^@^@^@ around them (I assume this is like a null character). Other than that theres nothing else nontext (no numbers or anything).

Comment: @Kevin How exactly does your teacher want this to be outputted? Only the actual strings in your binary are going to be readable when you're printing. If you have a byte with a value of 1, '1' won't be printed in the terminal. Look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), the value for the ASCII character '1' is 0x31 (or 49 in decimal). Unless you create some sort of hex viewer or something, binary files are going to show mostly garbage. Or perhaps are you trying to make a copy of the file? Either way, it makes no sense to use `fgets` for binary data.